# GeoServer WFS datastore PostGIS - submission hanging when there are multiple polygons / points

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wfs, datastore

I have an web application in PHP / Symfony that communicates with the GeoServer in order to submit and retrieve points and polygons. The GeoServer communicates with a PostgreSQL database, where it saves the points and polygons through WFS.

I had my GeoServer in an older version (1.8snapshot) and server (Ubuntu16),and now I migrated to a new server (Ubuntu22), and took the opportunity to bump GeoServer version to 1.21.

The problem I'm having is related with these WFS communications. When I draw a polygon in my web map application and it is submitted to the GeoServer via WFS (both polygon and respective points), it works when it's just one or two with a few points. But when I draw more and more polygons and points in bigger quantities (and it doesn't need to be that more, 3 polygons with 20 points each will be enough to make it crash), the Tomcat Java process hangs forever and consumes a lot of CPU (100% basically) and it stays like this forever (or until I restart the Tomcat service). The process I'm talking about is the one that runs in "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java". If I use only 1 or 2 polygons with a few points, those processes finish and don't hang. But after a certain amount of points/polygons, it never finishes and hangs forever.

Could anyone provide feedback on how to solve this problem? It's important to mention that I didn't had these problems before the migration.

geoserver logs:

```
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: district_code. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: district_code. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: district_code. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: municipality_code. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: municipality_code. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: municipality_code. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lat. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lat. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lat. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lng. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lng. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lng. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosLayer. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosLayer. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosLayer. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosDrone. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosDrone. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosDrone. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: polygon TransactionEventType[PreInsert]
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid","process_id","step_id",encode(ST_AsBinary("polygon"), 'base64') as "polygon","type","plantusage","updatedat","estimatedquality","name","obs","photofilenames","datefeature","timefeature" FROM "public"."polygon" WHERE 0 = 1
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting fid to 0
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 0 to 0
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting process_id to 80
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 1 to 80
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting step_id to 4467
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 2 to 4467
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting polygon to POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785))
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 3 to POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785))
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting type to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 4 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting plantusage to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 5 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting updatedat to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 6 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting estimatedquality to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 7 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting name to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 8 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting obs to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 9 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting photofilenames to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 10 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting datefeature to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 11 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting timefeature to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 12 to null
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Inserting new feature: INSERT INTO "public"."polygon" ( "process_id","step_id","polygon","type","plantusage","updatedat","estimatedquality","name","obs","photofilenames","datefeature","timefeature" ) VALUES ( 80,4467,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785))', 4326),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('"public"."polygon"', 'fid')
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT currval('public.polygon_fid_seq')
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: polygon TransactionEventType[PostInsert]
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = https://dummy_ip_replaced/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@a0b8307 (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:polygon=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: fid<fid id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: process_id<process_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=80, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: step_id<step_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=4467, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: polygon<polygon id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785)), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: type<type id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: plantusage<plantusage id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: updatedat<updatedat id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: estimatedquality<estimatedquality id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: name<name id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: obs<obs id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: photofilenames<photofilenames id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: datefeature<datefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: timefeature<timefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    insert[0]:
        feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:polygon=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: fid<fid id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: process_id<process_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=80, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: step_id<step_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=4467, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: polygon<polygon id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785)), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: type<type id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: plantusage<plantusage id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: updatedat<updatedat id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: estimatedquality<estimatedquality id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: name<name id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: obs<obs id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: photofilenames<photofilenames id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: datefeature<datefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: timefeature<timefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null]
        idgen = GenerateNew
        inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    releaseAction = ALL
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" took 400ms
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[polygon.1587]
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "public"."polygon" WHERE ("fid" = '1587') LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - _Id is abstract
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = https://dummy_ip_replaced/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [ polygon.1587 ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = polygon
    outputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    resultType = results
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: http://opengeo.org
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[polygon.1587]
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid","process_id","step_id",encode(ST_AsBinary("polygon"), 'base64') as "polygon","type","plantusage","updatedat","estimatedquality","name","obs","photofilenames","datefeature","timefeature" FROM "public"."polygon" WHERE ("fid" = '1587') LIMIT 1000000
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" took 63ms
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:44 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:44 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 009 15:09:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 009 15:09:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 009 15:09:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 009 15:09:44 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hi @IanTurton i've followed what you suggested but there aren't any relevant information in the logs related to the problem i'm having

Comment: I doubt that - if you turn up the logging level to GEOTOOLS_DEV and rerun the query it will take you through every step in the process in great detail - this is called relevant information

Comment: @IanTurton i edited my question and added a link that  contains the geoserver logs that occurred when i've done the request.

Comment: you need to add the relevant part of the log to the question, no one is going to click a random link

Comment: @IanTurton Sorry, the part of the log to the question is still quite bit, even though i tried to filter as much as possible to avoid publishing a big post. Nonetheless, i tried to filter as much as possible information to edit the post and add it here. You can now see the logs

Comment: Your log shows the process working perfectly - I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: @IanTurton That was what i feared. I've been stuck in this problem without knowing what more can i do. Any tips?

Comment: find the log file entry for a transaction that hangs